# Help with figuring out the particular requirements of this circuit

Tags: circuit-analysis, brushless-dc-motor, supercapacitor

Sorry for if i say anything incorrect

I am trying to create a circuit  that can control a BLDC. motor  ...quite simple and easy but i want the source of power to be switchable/interchangeable  ...orignally  from a battery then when a switch is pressed for the power to come from a  super capacitor  bank ...the capacitor bank will of course also be recharged by  another method

my issus comes as i am unsure about the correct requirements , specifies and how many super capacitors should be in parallel  and series in order to give the same output as the battery as i do not want the ESC to cut out...[image: a simple representation of the circuit]

Comment: That's not very realistically viable.  Have you calculated the capacitance you would need?  And noted that supercapacitors typically have much lower voltage?

Comment: yeah that was what i was worried about  ...i understood it would be an issue but was unsure how to make it a reality

Comment: For your computations use energy units (Joules or Wh). If the battery (11.1V x 3Ah = 33.3Wh) will run your motor for a specific time, determine how many Wh do you need in the supercapacitors to run the motor for another specific time.

Comment: It's not really going to be something you can make a reality.  Back up to your actual goal and find a more realistic solution.  Look at how existing solutions to that problem work (for example, with sufficient care - which is not trivial - they may recharge the battery back with energy momentarily available, for example from braking)

Comment: maybe this link will help.    https://youtu.be/xmrSv76yhio

Comment: he managed  to make something similar ..of course hes using a battery to charge the SC beforehand but the capacitor s are still running the motor  ....other than like 4 seconds of footage ( ill find the specific point) there isnt much explanation  on how it works

Comment: at the 1:26 mark he shows more or less all the electronics

Comment: Do you want the supercapacitors to run the motor for the same time as the battery or shorter ?

Comment: of course not for the same amount of time ...tbh i didnt really make that clear  .... no itll  only run the motor for a few seconds or so ...nothing major

Comment: You have not provided enough information for even a wild guess about how many capacitors are required.  Do you know how low the voltage can go without the ESC cutting out? I believe a voltage was mentioned in the YouTube you linked in a comment. If that applies, put it in the question. If any other facts and figures from the YouTube apply put them in the question. I watched the video, but I didn't copy down any data and I am not going to do that. All data that applies should be in the question, not in a YouTube or in a comment.

Comment: Do you know the ESC minimum operating voltage ? The entire supercapacitor energy (CU^2/2) is available when you discharge it down to zero volts, which is not practical in real-life situation. So you want to use the supercap only as a "booster" to get more power that the batteries can deliver for a short time ?

Comment: You need an estimate of the average current required during the run time. You should have a specific objective for the operating time needed when powered from the capacitor bank. A few seconds or so is not a specific objective. It might help to know why you want this dual source scheme.